# How to show additional names between 2 tables on a 3rd lookup col

Tags: worksheet-function

Hi sorry for the overkill in the details in the earlier post-

1. I have 2 lists of names on 2 sheets (master and data) in 1 xls file.
2. I currently use =XLOOKUP($A2,'RPV Data'!$B:$B,'RPV Data'!$A:$A, "...") on the master sheet to find what names match master to data.
3. I was hoping to do a nested xlookup (or another formula) to also show what extra names are in data but not in master. ie jon Doe only in data only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, this is not a "send my sheet to someone" kind of website. Please: 1. Format your question with parapgraphs and Markdown so that it's comprehensible. 2. Make it as detailed as possible here, with words, not with a sheet file. 3. Also, state what app are you working with. Excel I assume? Which version of it?

Comment: Hi All, Is this now more clear? Is it possible? as google has let me down with an answer - hoping you SME's can assist.